# Infinite recursion with tidy after subseting list of nls - fits in r

Tags: r

I fitted a model to the following data and want to use the tidy function from the "broom"-package to summarize the model outcomes.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(minpack.lm)
library(broom)

Sample = as.factor(c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"))
X = c(0.0,2.1,7.0,9.2,14.0,16.1,42.0,49.0,56.1,65.1,79.0,91.0,105.0,119.2,133.0,147.0,163.0,183.1,219.0,10.0,12.1,17.0,19.1,24.0,26.1,52.0,59.0,66.1,75.2,89.0,101.0,115.0,129.1,143.0,157.0,173.0,193.1,229.0)
Y = c(0.0,1.3,7.4,11.7,16.6,18.0,36.8,39.5,42.5,46.3,51.8,57.3,61.5,64.0,67.6,74.7,72.5,76.9,83.4,20.3,25.0,31.8,36.3,41.6,43.4,68.0,71.8,76.3,81.5,88.2,95.5,101.7,105.6,111.5,115.2,119.3,126.4,132.8)
df = data.frame(Sample,X,Y)

 #doing the fit wraped in try() because some models fail because of the wrong starting values
dfSample = df %>% group_by(Sample) %>%
  do(fitSample = try(nlsLM(Y~CA*(1-exp(-k1*X))+CB*(1-exp(-k2*X)), data = .,
                       start=list(k1=(0.07), k2=(0.08),  CA=7, CB=23))))

#subsetting for successful models
elim = "Error in nlsModel"
dfSamplei = subset(dfSample, !grepl(paste(elim), dfSample$fitSample))

#tidy the outcome
dfSampleCoef = tidy(dfSamplei, fitSample)

#Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
#Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)
```

tidy workes well with data not subsetted by the subset function but did the error after subsetting. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: The seems that the subset drops the groups which seems to throw off tidy. I appears that `dfSampleCoef = tidy(dfSamplei %>% rowwise(), fitSample)` would fix the problem. I can't fully address "why" so maybe someone else can give the exact reason and provide a more complete answer

Comment: You're using plyr *and* dplyr? I think it's generally recommended to use one of the 2, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the number of allowed nests with the `options(expressions = 10000)` but what's happening under the hood is that the deep nesting is causing `Error: protect(): protection stack overflow`, which you can't get around just by increasing the value of `expressions`.

Instead, I recommend that you take Mr.Flick's suggestion from the comments and use:

`dfSampleCoef = tidy(dfSamplei %>% rowwise(), fitSample)`

instead of the problematic line of code.

A less optimal solution would be to increase point stack size when R starts:

`R --max-pp-size=100000`